# Raster image drawing software/library with deepzoom

Tags: image, drawing, 2d, deepzoom

I'm looking for a raster image *drawing* software with an "infinite" zoom capability like the image viewer [SeaDragon(YouTube-link)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKwTurQgiak&t=1m36s). Or, alternatively, a library (in any language) with which one could build such a drawing software.

I want to draw images without having to think about resolution, being able to add ("infinite") detail wherever I feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for [DeepZoom Composer](http://dzc.wisestar.net/).  There are a number of projects starting up at [OpenZoom](http://openzoom.org/) as well.  Although this is relatively new, so the quality is still rather rough.

Comment: No, it only lets you assemble multiple images into one big one. You can't directly draw like in photoshop for example.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the piccolo project: http://www.piccolo2d.org/  There is a demo app for drawing which might do what you want, but it's quite easy to make your own.  Java + C# versions were pretty good last I checked (last used the Java version about 3 years ago).